# Fixed positioned element issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, css-transitions

```
<nav>
</nav>

<div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-side">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 middle-side">
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-side">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

CSS code

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: var(--main-bg2-color);
  margin-top: 55.6px !important;
}

.wrapper.row {
  margin: 0;
}

.left-side {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: var(--main-bg2-color);
  color: var(--main-text-color);
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 41px;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.middle-side {
  padding-top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-bg2-color);
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 14%;
}

.right-side {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-bg2-color);
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

Here I have a container inside it the left-side class and right side class must remain fixed while the middle side class must be scrollable. My issue is that right side class is always on right with respect to the window when I give right:0. I want right-side class must be right:0 with respect to wrapper class
Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: This not right way to use position fixed, cause its parent is page.
change position fixed to absolute and add top: 0 to right-side and left-side

Comment: I am sorry I didn't post the whole code. My parent is not page.

Comment: I know, it dosent matter what the parent is, position fixed parent is always page.

Comment: I have used position sticky instead of fixed but its not working

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want the child div to be fixed to it's parent...

in order to do so you have to set the parent to be positioned fixed and then all its children to be positioned absolute.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't post the whole code. My issue is that when I give right side class right:0 it always go to right w.r.t window. I want right-side class must be right:0 with respect to wrapper class.

Comment: When using position fixed the values of top,bottom,left and right will be relative to the window always. so I think this can't be done unless you have the parent element fixed and children have to be absolute and they will be relative to the container only